# How to go to other page with data by method buildResults

Tags: flutter, dart

I use Class SearchDelegate to search and show the result by buildResults.
I want to send the resulting data to another page through buildResults, what should I do?

```
 @override
 Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
   return
   /*i want go to other page with data*/
 }
 @override
 Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
  var searchBook ;
    searchBook = query.isEmpty ? list: list['name_book'].where((p) => p.startsWith(query)).toList();
   return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, i) {
         return ListTile(leading: Icon(Icons.book, color: Colors.green,),onTap: (){
           query=searchBook[i]['id_book'];
           showResults(context);},
           title: Text("${searchBook[i]['name_book']}"),);},
     itemCount: searchBook.length,
   );
 }
```